# Edit the Ionic starter side menu app header

Tags: ionic-framework

Started with Ionic but want to add a new button to the right of my apps header.

However, in my index.html I only have this:

```
<body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
```

And cannot find how to edit the header? Im guessing its generated in a template somewhere, but no searching is returning anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a working example... here it is:

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
  .state('onepage', {
    url: '/1',
    templateUrl: 'onepage.html'
  })
  
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/1");
})
```

```html
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title>Ionic Template</title>
    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive nav-title-slide-ios7" align-title="center">
      <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon ion-arrow-left-c">
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-nav-view class="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>

    <script id="onepage.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <!-- The title of the ion-view will be shown on the navbar -->
      <ion-view title="onepage">
        <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
          <button class="button">
            LeftButton
          </button>
        </ion-nav-buttons>        
        <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
          <button class="button button-assertive">
            RightButton
          </button>
        </ion-nav-buttons>        

        <ion-content class="padding">
          <!-- The content of the page -->
          <h3>Bla bla bla</h3>
          <p>Bla bla bla</p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script> 

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this [codepen](http://codepen.io/NewbieDev/pen/EPLQJa)

```
<ion-nav-bar>
</ion-nav-bar>
<ion-nav-view>
  <ion-view>
    <ion-nav-buttons side="primary">
      <button class="button" ng-click="doSomething()">
        I'm a button on the primary of the navbar!
      </button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <ion-content>
      Some super content here!
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</ion-nav-view>
```

Available sides: `primary`, `secondary`, `left`, and `right`

Comment: does this overwrite the one thats included with the template? I understand how to edit the files but do not know where to find the code itself.

Comment: @Lovelock what code do u want to find? I didnt get you

Comment: if you want same button in every page, keep it in index.html page otherwise keep it in the required page @Lovelock